# Using dynamic data taken from jsp

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch

In following code, I take static data in nested list. But in place of static data, I want dynamic data i.e the data taken from jsp. I don't know how to do that.

```
Ext.define('SenchaApp.store.Items', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        model: 'SenchaApp.model.Item',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        root: {
            items: [
            {
                text: 'Categories1',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories1',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories2',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories3',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories4',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },

                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'Categories2',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories1',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories2',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories3',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories4',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },

                ]
            },
             {
                text: 'Categories3',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories1',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories2',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories3',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories4',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },

                ]
            },
             {
                text: 'Categories4',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories1',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories2',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories3',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Subcategories4',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Product1', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product2', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product3', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Product4', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },

                ]
            },
        ]
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: in the above code, you show an inline store with filled data. What do you mean by "dynamic"? Is that kind of sending a JSONP request, get back the nested-list data and fill in your nestedlist component?

Comment: yes.i want take data from jsp.

Comment: i hardcode the data but i want take the data from jsp

Comment: i am new to senchatouch.i don't know what way use jsp in senchatouch.

Comment: how can we convert jsp data to jsonp.

Comment: wait a moment, I'm writing the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much Thiem Nguyen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not have to use JSONP here. It's much easier to use Ajax request with a JSON reader.

According to your code, I suppose that your model definition should be something like this:

```
Ext.define('SenchaApp.model.Item', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: ['text'],
        }
});
```

Then this will fetch JSONP from the server and fill your Store:

```
Ext.define('SenchaApp.store.Items', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        model: 'SenchaApp.model.Item',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: enter_your_api_url_here,
            extraParams: {set your extra params if needed},
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

PS: If it does not work, please copy & paste your jsonp file link here and I'll help you.

Comment: if you're satisfied with the answer, you should vote it up and check it as accepted answer to close this question, according to Stack Overflow's rule